# Expected tax (GST) when eating out in India?

Tags: india, money, local-customs

So I have eaten out several times in India and every time the amount of tax on the final bill seems to be different.

Sometimes it is 9.5% other times two lots of 2.5% (cGST & sGST?)

Also on a couple of occasions when I also had a beer the tax was 25% and 20% + 11% (on the VAT)

Let's say I order Rs1000 of food off the menu and a Rs100 beer.

**What should the tax be on that restaurant bill?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the GST rate is 5% (2.5% state and 2.5% center) as you noticed.

> In November of 2017, the GST council met and decided to make changes
>   to the original restaurant tax rates. During this meeting, the council
>   set the GST rate at just 5% for most restaurants, regardless of AC and
>   liquor licenses

I'm not sure about the 9.5% number, but restaurants in high end hotels will charge 18%

> If you run a restaurant in a hotel, however, the rules might be
>   different. For restaurants in hotels with standard room rates of
>   RS7500 per night or higher, the GST is set at 18%. The 18% rate also
>   applies to outdoor catering.

The alcohol rate might depend on the state.

> If you serve alcohol in your restaurant, your taxes are slightly more
>   complicated. The GST regime does not include liquor. That means that
>   when a diner orders a drink, you need to tax that drink at different
>   rates. Depending on where your restaurant is in India, that could
>   include VAT and any other applicable state taxes. These taxes must
>   only be applied to the alcohol part of the bill, while the GST must
>   only be applied to the food section of the bill.

The above quotes are from https://quickbooks.intuit.com/in/resources/gst-center/gst-restaurant-owners/